# Is this really how AUTO_INCREMENT works?

Tags: sql

I'm new to sql, I just wanted to know if this is normal. Here's my table structure:

[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSOv2.png)

So I tried deleting all the data but for some reason when I try to input a new data, the `id` increments. For example, I put a data with an `id` of 1 and then I delete that data then input a new one, that new data gives me an id of 2 even if I delete the first one. I wanted to know if that's normal for auto_increment.

Comment: Yes, Truncate the table and it will start again

Comment: that is normal - use `truncate` to reset auto-increment count

Comment: @RamRaider Do I just `truncate` and that's it? Or do I have to `truncate` everytime?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Ids are usually used to cross-reference data between different tables. You would not want to reuse ids and have a reference suddenly refer to different data!

Comment: To reset the auto-increment count you would "truncate `tablename`;" any time you wished to delete all the content and reset the counter

Comment: @RamRaider Is there a way for the table to automatically truncate whenever I delete data?

Comment: @deceze I know that but this `id` I'm talking about is not really the id. I might rename this to message_no or something. employee_id is the one you're talking about

Comment: @MarkZ You’ve asked why the auto-increment column keeps increasing, I gave the reason. Auto-increment keeps *incrementing*, it’s not called auto-contiguous-numbers-without-gaps.

Comment: truncating the table deletes all the data and resets the counter in a single operation. If you want to delete a few records and have the counter reset to the next available ID then `ALTER TABLE <TABLENAME> AUTO_INCREMENT=1;` should do it

Comment: @RamRaider Alright thanks, you can post your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please tag ur DBMS:

In MYSQL :-

**Auto Increment:**

By default, the starting value for the AUTO_INCREMENT is 1, and it will increment by 1 for each time when the new record is created.

For more info please visit: https://www.1keydata.com/sql/auto-increment.html and http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-reset-auto-increment